# HttpMessage.setMethod(HttpMessage.POST) is changed by GET, on BlockingSenderDestination

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile, soap

I am trying to migrate a Blackberry application from OS 6 to OS 7 (my app currently works on OS 6). Theoretically it should not cause any problems, but I found an issue that I still cannot resolve. When executing calls to web services (SOAP), I'm setting the HttpMessages to use the POST method, but when the call is executed, it arrives at the server as a GET. This is a big problem for me because the Sever with which am working doesn't support GET's (always results in an "Http 500 error"). This issue doesn't occur on the simulator, just on the device.

Do you know any workaround for this? Is it a problem with OS version? (See below for the code that I'm using).

### Device

Model: Bold 9930
Carrier: Sprint
OS: 7.0 Bundle 1296 (v7.0.0.241, Platform 5.0.0.442)

### Simulator (On the simulator side I don't have any problems)

Model: Bold 9930
OS: 7.0 Bundle 1962(v7.0.0.440, Sept_24_2011_signed, Platform 4.0.0.141)

```
public void run() {
        context.setEnableBtnsend(false);
        BlockingSenderDestination blockSendDest = null;

        try {
            URI uri = URI.create(URL_BASE);
            blockSendDest
                = (BlockingSenderDestination) DestinationFactory.getSenderDestination(
                senderContext.getName(), uri);

            if (blockSendDest == null) {
                blockSendDest = DestinationFactory.createBlockingSenderDestination(
                    senderContext, uri);
            }

            ByteMessage requestMessage = blockSendDest.createByteMessage();
            requestMessage.setTransportHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            requestMessage.setTransportHeader("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
            // getBodyRequest() -> Insert SOAP request, works fine, was tested on SOAP UI
            requestMessage.setStringPayload(getBodyRequest());
            ((HttpMessage) requestMessage).setMethod(HttpMessage.POST);
            blockSendDest.resume();
            Message response = blockSendDest.sendReceive(requestMessage);

            if (response != null) {
                procesMessageResponse(response);
            }
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
             handleException(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a bad proxy messing with things between the server and the device? Also, a server that returns a 500 error, according to the HTTP spec, is not indicating that it doesn't support the GET method. That would be a 405 or a 501 error.

Comment: I've tried from some different places (On my office on my home), have debugged on the server side, on that I could see that the message arrived using GET method, currently on the server application with which I'm trying to make the app, doesn't have supports for GET methods, the complete response that I've from the server is <faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /axis2/services/SystemService and the WSA Action = null</faultstring>, I cannot understand is why the message always arrived with GET method?

Comment: Also, my app works well from devices that have OS 6, and from simulator Bold 9930 OS 7, the unique difference between calls is the HTTP method, with which is arrives at the server